# Transforming x,y coordinates from Tkinter into latitude and longitude?

Tags: tkinter

So i'm currently working on a project and i'm making a GeoGuessr type game.

I display a map on Tkinter and I can get the x and y coordinates of the mouse when she's pressed.

I've searched a function to convert my x, y coordinates into lattitude and longitude but I couldn't find anything..

Can someody help me?

Edit : the map is 1440x715 ( I can resize it if needed ) and my window is thre same size. [The map](https://www.zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/08/wjc1.png)

Comment: If you know the display range of latitudes and longitudes, then it is a simple maths.

Comment: The conversion of x,y to lon,lat completely depends on how you display the map. Please edit your question to show what kind of map you display and how (read [mcve]).

Comment: Done, I also linked the map if you want

Comment: Have a look at geopandas and assocrated libraries to convert between easting (x), northing (y) and longitudes and lattitudes. See this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/converting-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python